# Accessing two models from a general class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I currently have two models mostly similar but connects to different tables

```
class MyModel1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def my_method
  end
end

class MyModel2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def my_method
  end
end
```

In many places I am fetching data conditionally like below

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def my_action
    item = my_condition ? MyModel1.find_by(code: 123) : MyModel2.find_by(code: 123)
    result = item.my_method
  end
end

class OtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def other_method(item_id)
    resp = my_condition ? MyModel1.find_by(code: item_id) : MyModel2.find_by(code: item_id)
    ...
  end
end
```

But this is becoming very hard to maintain this type of checks in all places. How can I generlise this? I know if we inherit from a parent model, then child class will have access to all parent model methods

```
class MyGeneralClass < MyModel1
  def initialize
    super
  end
end 

item = MyGeneralClass.find_by(code: 123)
```

But I am not getting how to add my checks in MyGeneralClass so that in other places I can  call required model methods. Something like below

```
class MyGeneralClass
  def initialize
    klass = my_condition ? MyModel1 : MyModel2
    klass.send(:private_instance_method) 
  end
end

item = MyGeneralClass.find_by(code: 123)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a simple module to your application that returns the desired record like this:

```
# in app/models/my_generic_model_finder.rb
module MyGenericModelFinder
  def self.find_by(condition, query)
    klass = condition ? MyModel1 : MyModel2
    klass.find_by(query)
  end
end
```

Which can be used in your controllers and models like this

```
MyGenericModelFinder.find_by(my_condition, code: 123)
```

Another solution could be to just return the correct model for your condition and then run all the queries like you would if you just had a normal model.

```
# in app/models/my_conditional_model.rb
module MyConditionalModel
  def self.for(condition)
    condition ? MyModel1 : MyModel2
  end
end
```

Which can be used in your controllers and models like this

```
MyConditionalModel.for(condition).find_by(code: 123)
```

Because `MyConditionalModel.for(condition)` returns a class you can do other queries too, like `MyConditionalModel.for(condition).where(foo: 'bar').order(...)`

Comment: I wanted to check is there any way to mimic `ActiveRecord` methods as well. With your suggestion, I might have to write methods in general class for standard methods like `where` as well?

Comment: That depends on how you actually use this finder, why you actually need to differentiate between both models, and how the condition looks like. Can you elaborate and add more examples to your question?

Comment: I updated my answer with another solution that might be a better fit for your use case when you want to be able to call methods like `where` or `count` on those models too.